# how to compare the files data in 2 different unix boxes

Tags: unix-shell

i have one file which exists in 2 different unix machines.
how i can compare the data with in the file

Answer (score 6):

You can compare files remotely using ssh:

```
$ ssh -p 2022 localhost "cat /remote_path" | diff - /local_path
$ ssh -p 2022 localhost "cat /etc/lsb-release" | diff - /etc/lsb-release
2,4c2,4
< DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
< DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
< DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
---
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS"
```

Or use sshfs/nfs.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply . actually i have list of files in one directory in 2 unix boxes . i need to compare all the files data between 2 unix boxes. how i can do for list of files data comparision in unix .

Comment: @Navadeep Use sshfs and 'diff -r'

Answer (score 1):

shortest way to figure if they are 'same' could be

md5sum file on each box, and compare if md5sums match (or some other sum)

if you want to diff them , copy one file over to other box and diff it.

Comment: `md5sum` isn't a way «to figure if they are 'same'». It's rather a way to figure out whether they're different, ЕВПОЧЯ. :-)

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply.actually i dont have write access in another unix box .i can only check the file data is same or not if the data is not same i need to send a mail....

Answer (score 1):

Remotely? Do you have NFS running? Is the directory containing the file of one of the machines mounted on the other machine? You could check this with " df ".

If you don't have NFS or the directory is not mounted you will have to copy the file. You could use " scp " to copy the file.

For comparing them use diff or if installed kdiff3 or mgdiff are nice. " diff -y " shows a side by side output.

Answer (score 0):

```
vimdiff file scp://login@server//pathto/file
```

the double / after server is not a typo